# AVPlayer values observed via NSKeyValueObservation are always nil

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, key-value-observing

I'm in the process of writing [Combine wrappers](https://github.com/jozsef-vesza/AVFoundation-Combine) around AVPlayer. Consider the following example (full source available [here](https://github.com/jozsef-vesza/AVFoundation-Combine/blob/master/AVFoundation-Combine/Publishers/PlayerRatePublisher.swift)):

```swift
private final class PlayerRateSubscription<S: Subscriber>: Subscription where S.Input == Float {
    // ...
    private var stateObserverToken: NSKeyValueObservation? = nil
    // ...
    
    func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) {
        // ...
        stateObserverToken = player.observe(\.rate) { [weak self] (player, change) in
            print(change.oldValue)
            print(change.newValue)
            print(player.rate)
            // ...
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

When I run that code, `change.oldValue` and `change.newValue` both end up being nil. However, `player.rate` will always return the correct rate.

I'm experiencing the same when observing the [playback status](https://github.com/jozsef-vesza/AVFoundation-Combine/blob/master/AVFoundation-Combine/Publishers/PlayerStatePublisher.swift#L50): `playerItem.status` returns the correct value, while the values from the KVO change are always nil. I feel that I should be able to get the old/new values from the `change` variable.

Am I misusing the API? Is this a known limitation in AVFoundation?

## Update

After some research I found the following bits in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift):

> Omitting the options parameter forgoes storing the new and old property values, which causes the oldValue and newValue properties to be nil.

After updating my implementation to this:

```swift
observationToken = observedObject.observe(keyPath, options: [.old, .new]) { [weak self] (object, change) in
    ...
}
```

some of the observed keypaths started working correctly.

Unfortunately not all of them: according to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/responding_to_playback_state_changes), `AVPlayerItem.status` should be key-value observable, yet `change.oldValue`, and `change.newValue` are both nil, which I find completely puzzling.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else is looking for this, this is a bug.
https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5872

**Update:**

bugs.swift was moved to github

Newest issue for this radar ID (SR-5872) since it has had some PRs that have been closed.

https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/issues/3807

Answer (score 0):

Not all properties are key-value observable by default.

For example in the documentation of `status` there is

> This property is key value observable using Key-value observing.

This line is missing in `rate`

Comment: I also experience the same behavior when observing `playerItem`'s `status` property (which is key-value observable), so I'm not sure that's it. Interestingly the KVO callback gets triggered, but the values are missing from the `change` object.